# AWS processing message, How to get delivery status of message processed from MESSAGEID

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-ses

To get status of send email is bounced/delivered/rejected, Please help out to get response of email to get status from messageid

`````
    const aws = require('aws-sdk');

    exports.handler = async (event) => {

    const { Records } = event;

    const body = JSON.parse(Records[0].body);

    var ses = new aws.SES({ region: "us-east-1" });
    var params = {
    Destination: {
      ToAddresses: body.to,
    },
    Message: {
      Body: {
        Html: {
          Data: body.body, // HTML content
        },
      },
      Subject: {
        Data: body.subject,
      },
    },
    Source: body.fromName + "<" + body.from + ">",
    };
    var result = await ses.sendEmail(params).promise();
    };````
`````